# I have a problem with inserting informations in mysql database

Tags: php, mysqli

im actully new to php and mysqli programing, im creating a login and registration form. I did some research on internet about coding and how to get this done and i'm getting problem with inserting information into mysql database, when i'm trying to register a user. I'm getting message " **SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined** "

```
require_once 'dbconfig.php';

class USER
{   
    private $conn;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $database = new Database();
        $db = $database->dbConnection();
        $this->conn = $db;
    }

    public function runQuery($sql)
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        return $stmt;
    }

    public function lasdID()
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->lastInsertId();
        return $stmt;
    }

    public function register($uname,$email,$upass,$code,$spol)
    {
        try
        {                           
            $password = md5($upass);
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_users(userName,userEmail,userPass,tokenCode,spol) 
                                                         VALUES(:user_name, :user_mail, :user_pass, :active_code, :spol)");
            $stmt->bindparam(":user_mail",$email);
            $stmt->bindparam(":user_pass",$password);
            $stmt->bindparam(":spol",$spol);
            $stmt->bindparam(":active_code",$code);
            $stmt->execute();   
            return $stmt;
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex)
        {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }

 public function login($email,$upass)
 {
  try
  {
   $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userEmail=:email_id");
   $stmt->execute(array(":email_id"=>$email));
   $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

   if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
   {
    if($userRow['userStatus']=="Y")
    {
     if($userRow['userPass']==md5($upass))
     {
      $_SESSION['userSession'] = $userRow['userID'];
      return true;
     }
     else
     {
      header("Location: index.php?narobe");
      exit;
     }
    }
    else
    {
     header("Location: index.php?inactive");
     exit;
    } 
   }
   else
   {
    header("Location: index.php?error");
    exit;
   }  
  }
  catch(PDOException $ex)
  {
   echo $ex->getMessage();
  }
 } 
 public function is_logged_in()
 {
  if(isset($_SESSION['userSession']))
  {
   return true;
  }
 }
 public function redirect($url)
 {
  header("Location: $url");
 }

 public function logout()
 {
  session_destroy();
  $_SESSION['userSession'] = false;
 }
```

i'm not sure if i made mistake inside of mysql table or i just typed a wrong code. 
If someone could help me to solve a problem than that will be amazing.

Here is image of mysql table

https://ibb.co/djfXDK0

Comment: Hi. Please check your query: you have 5 placeholders, but you are assigning only 4 with bind param. I guess you are not binding ":user_name".

Comment: you have 5 parameter but 4 times using bindParam . $stmt->bindparam(":user_name",$name) is missing

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text or using MD5/SHA1!** Only store password hashes. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I really hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) library to get the same functionality.

Comment: Are you sure that you are ok with user `latin1_swedish_ci` collation? I would recommend to switch all your tables to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

Comment: @BenRoob yeah i saw that haha, thanks for helping me out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the $uname parameter to your binding parameters, you forgot a line of code:

```
    $password = md5($upass);
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_users(userName,userEmail,userPass,tokenCode,spol) 
                                                 VALUES(:user_name, :user_mail, :user_pass, :active_code, :spol)");
    $stmt->bindparam(":user_name",$uname);
    $stmt->bindparam(":user_mail",$email);
    $stmt->bindparam(":user_pass",$password);
    $stmt->bindparam(":spol",$spol);
    $stmt->bindparam(":active_code",$code);
    $stmt->execute();
```

You shouldn´t use **MD5** as hash for the password, you should use the php built in functions **password_hash()** and **password_verify()**